# Trying to upadate my wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I tried internet but didn't find solution. So here is my problem that when i try to update my wordpress I get this error.
 Warning: unlink(C:\Windows\TEMP/wordpress-4.tmp): Permission denied in E:\wamp\www\monarch\wp-admin\includes\file.php on line 503

I thinks I have to allow wordpreess update in file.php but where and how, I don't know. SO I need help in this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try disabling your plugins.

Comment: thanks for replying, I tried to do so but got same error

Comment: You can change your file permissions by rightclicking on the uploads folder in your ftp software. Change it to 777. This gives everyone the right to read, write and execute. In some cases this is needed before you can upload. Change it to 775 after you are done.

Comment: right click - file permissions.